# Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.string'

Tags: java, android

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final TextView label1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.label1);
    final TextView label2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.label2);
    final EditText introducir=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.introducir);
    Button probar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.probar);

    final Random dado=new Random();

    final String numTxt="";

    probar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int cont=0;
            cont=cont+1;
            int num=5/*dado.nextInt(100)+1*/;

            num=Integer.parseInt(numTxt);

        if (introducir.getText().toString()==numTxt){

            label1.setText("¡¡¡HAS ACERTADO!!!");
            label2.setText("");


        }
        if (introducir.getText().toString()>numTxt){
            label1.setText("¿"+num+"? ¡Uy! El número que he pensado es mayor");
            label2.setText("");
        }


        }
    });
```

The error is on this line:

if (introducir.getText().toString()>numTxt)

I don't understand the error because I have made the cast, so can somebody help me? Please.
Thanks.

Comment: What cast did you make? You can't use the greater than operator with either of its operands being a String. I'm not sire how much more clear the error can be.

Comment: Unless you are trying to compare the lengths of two things, you cannot do that with Strings in Java; first get the length then use the operator

Comment: What kind of comparison are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not compare `String` with ">" so the solution that I give to you is:

Since you are gettint it from an `EditText` the result will be a `String` so you have two options :

1.- Use `Integer.valueOf()`

```
try{

  int val = Integer.valueOf(introducir.getText().toString())

}catch(NumberFormatException e){

 Toast.makeText(this, "El valor no es un entero",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

2.- Use `Integer.parseInt()`

```
try{

  int val = Integer.parseInt(introducir.getText().toString())

}catch(NumberFormatException e){

 Toast.makeText(this, "El valor no es un entero",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

then you can use `if(val>num){}`

Hope it was clear.

Comment: Ohhh it's som simple. Thank you very much dude.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to compare a string using the comparator operator like '>', '>='

In this case you have to compare the string using compareTo method

it will return -1,0,1 where the value 0 means if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string.